# Firefox SDK using JQuery Draggable UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox-addon-sdk

i want to use this: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ in my Firefox SDK Addon.

This is the source code for a simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My Problem is, that i dont know how to handle the  function

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

in my content script, by using port communication between my main and content script.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you placed the draggable function in a page script, not a content script, making communication [way too complicated](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html#Using%20Custom%20DOM%20Events).

Instead, place all of your jQuery files and create a javascript file (let's call it `draggable.js`) in the `data` folder of your add-on (this is the content script) and place the `draggable` function there. Then use [`tabs.attach`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#attach%28options%29) like so.

### main.js

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
var worker;
var widget = require("sdk/widget").Widget({
    id: "mozilla-icon",
    label: "My Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico"
    onClick: function() {
        worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery.js'),
                data.url('jquery-ui.js'),
                data.url('draggable.js')]
        });
        worker.port.on("anything", function(variable) {
            console.log("Got variable: "+variable);
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can communicate with the script by using [`self.port.emit`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html) in `draggable.js` and `worker.on` in `main.js`

**Update**: Edited main.js and draggable.js will look like this:

### draggable.js

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
self.port.emit("anything", variable);
```

You should do anything that pertains to the page in this `draggable.js` and only send variables out if you need access to any Firefox sdk modules (which are only accessible in main.js).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answere, but it did not work this way... maybe i am using the ports wrong...
I want my draggable element in the current tab, not inside of my panel is that possible?

Comment: The above is for injecting in a tab, not a panel. I've made the code more explicit. If you are having problems, please post any errors you're coming across.